# Why haven't these answers that don't answer the question been removed?

Tags: discussion, answers

Recently, someone asked the question [Does it go against netiquette to give constructive feedback on Facebook?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/does-it-go-against-netiquette-to-give-constructive-feedback-on-facebook/), which I thought was an OK question. The answers, on the other hand...

The most egrigious answer is also the top voted answer ([link](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6817/does-it-go-against-netiquette-to-give-constructive-feedback-on-facebook/)). If you read the answer carefully, you'll see that it doesn't actually answer the question. The question asks about the norms of facebook groups. That answer essentially says in many words that what the OP did was fine and should be OK. But as has been said many times, this isn't tellmewhatyouwanttohear.stackexchange.com. An answer to that question should explain what netiquette in a particular community *actually is*, not what it *should be*.

I flagged the answer as not an answer. The flag was marked as helpful, but the answer wasn't removed. Could it be removed?

Comment: I think the question has more problems than that answer, now that you point it out. I'm asking 2 things at once, one about netiquette, the other about handling the moderator.... Given that, and [this meta](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2135/1599), it might still be around because it gave feedback on 'how to handle the moderator'. And, as far as I'm reading the answer, the OP there basically states, I'm not familiar with any specific netiquette for Facebook groups (as more users did), but what you did didn't seem out of line ;-)

Answer (score 6):

*I'm sorry, but the answer **did** answer the question.*

Asked question:

> Does it go against netiquette to provide constructive feedback in a Facebook group?

The posted answer:

> In general, however, this doesn't seem to be out of line. ... [More comments along these lines.]

It is up the responder to decide what to explain to get their idea across. So it is not strictly required to write a study on what netiquette is or isn't. Strictly speaking, "No" would have been sufficient to answer this question as it was phrased.

---

Asked question:

> If not, how do I explain so to the moderator and ask them to put something up in their rules so other people won't make the same mistake, without a risk of getting kicked from the group?

The posted answer:

> You could explain your point that they specifically asked for feedback and that in a PM you had an amicable exchange, so no offense was given: ... [Many more statements supporting this idea.]

---

Granted that the question, and thus all the answers, are in a grey area. But the consensus among the membership is that it is OK enough.

Another indicator for you is the overwhelming consensus is that this post is quite good: 82 upvotes (and counting) with just 1 downvote. (Come to think of it, I haven't voted -- yet.)

Comment: I agree with everything but the last paragraph; votes shouldn't be used as an indicator of whether or not an answer should be deleted or left alone.

Answer (score 5):

## Thanks for bringing this to my attention

I did not realise my answer was lacking, though I must say a comment would've sufficed.

I think you didn't interpret the question entirely correctly:

> **Does it go against netiquette to provide constructive feedback in a Facebook group? If not, how do I explain so to the moderator and ask them to put something up in their rules so other people won't make the same mistake, without a risk of getting kicked from the group?**

1. Does it go against netiquette to provide constructive feedback in a Facebook group?

This is a general question, about groups in general.

> In general, however, this doesn't seem to be out of line. It doesn't sound like you were simply bashing the OP, or even trying to be hurtful.
>
> Furthermore, they specifically asked for feedback (...) .

I further expanded the answer to comment on the netiquette in this group in particular.

2. If not, how do I explain so to the moderator and ask them to put something up in their rules so other people won't make the same mistake, without a risk of getting kicked from the group?

The rest of my answer is dedicated **to the actual Interpersonal question**, how to respond to the moderator. I slightly changed the wording of the answer to reflect the response more properly.