# Should we add the (red) faq tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Today, I spend almost 20 minutes looking for the meta post "How do I write a good answer?". Spoiler alert, the post that I clearly remember upvoting doesn't exist because this post was about *questions* not answers.

Instead, I finally manage to find [this discussion](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/what-do-we-expect-from-an-answer-on-interpersonal-skills).

However, I would have found it more quickly if we were using the (red) faq tag, like what they have on [meta Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/tagged/faq) (and on other meta).

So, if you think that a faq tag would be a good idea, here are some discussion that, I think, could benefice for such a tag:

- [How do I write a good question?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question/3230)
- [What do we expect from an answer on Interpersonal Skills?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/what-do-we-expect-from-an-answer-on-interpersonal-skills)

(If you have more, feel free to add it in an answer).

Comment: Ideally, when [meta-tag:faq-proposed] meta posts are finalized, they would be retagged into [meta-tag:faq]. There's more information on how "faq-proposed" tag works on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/info)

Comment: I think @Tinkeringbell is already working on the faq refactoring right now. That's nice that you raised it though.

Comment: @avazula I know that it might still be a "work in progress" but I think that it is already good enough to be useful. And in order to be "extra useful", using the "faq" tag sound like a good idea.

Comment: I meant that I'm pretty sure this has already been raised and should be applied soon :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: [The FAQ index](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/faq-for-interpersonal-skills) has been updated and all posts linked there have been tagged with [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)!**

Writing a FAQ is in progress! Mod Tinkeringbell has been [working on it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/61165?m=46676711#46676711) behind the scenes :) Once it's ready, we'll start tagging the FAQ posts with the official tag. You can read (and edit, and vote on) the current set of proposed FAQ questions and answers here: [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed)

In the meantime, we have a few posts tagged [policy](/questions/tagged/policy). This is a regular tag, so any user can add it to a post. The tag description is:

> Policies contain sitewide consensus about the rules on Interpersonal Skills. Use this on questions trying to establish a general consensus about policies on the site.

So, right now that tag is a good place to check for posts you can reference (the one you found here is tagged with that already).

I've also starred a few meta posts that I reference frequently, since you can easily look up your favorited posts by going to your meta user profile.

Answer (score 3):

I've finished writing, finally! The final post can be found at [How do I write a good answer?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3266/1599).

I've incorporated every positively scored point from [What do we expect from an answer on Interpersonal Skills?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2421/what-do-we-expect-from-an-answer-on-interpersonal-skills), and added a few too. The post I wrote has the same formatting as the '[How do I write a good question?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question/3230)' post as well, and a little more details per 'good answer' point.

If people rather have the 'What do we expect from an answer' post tagged as faq, I'd like to hear from them (please let me know why you think that one is better, please), otherwise, we'll likely be adding the faq tag to both the 'How do I write' posts in the near future.

Remember, nothing is set in stone (yet). Both the question and answer faq proposals I've written are made community wiki, so feel free to add or edit!