# Why do you think this answer should be deleted?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I posted [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/23364/8855). I haven't received an overwhelming negative response or anything, but someone downvoted and someone voted to delete.

Since no feedback has been left I am intrigued as to why people may think my answer should be deleted.

Could you give me some feedback? I don't think my answer is the same than Harper's, but they certainly overlap a bit. Also I actually like Harper's answer, that is why I didn't go into detail regarding how to handle the "procastination" aspect. In my answer I focus on agreeing on the refund, while Harper suggests working around the procastinator part.

Comment: [**Very related.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215397/232439) It looks like one downvote and one delete vote, which could reasonably have both been from the same person. Asking "Why do you think this answer should be deleted?" seems pretty opinion based. Only one person of our [23,000 users](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3888/11811) thought it was worth deleting. I'm not sure what we can tell you here outside of making up reasons that some other random person on the internet may feel a certain way.

Comment: @scohe001 yes it is opinion based but I wanted some feedback to see if I could improve my answer and avazula gave me good advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I read it very quickly, but it seems you're not providing backup in the shape of personal experience or literature citations. Since this is a [prerequisite for posting answers](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-ips-stack-exchange) on IPS, I'd think this is why someone voted to delete it. If you have trouble figuring how to provide this information after reading the post linked above let us know, we're here to help.

Comment: ahh I see, sometimes I forget to do that when I am referring to myself. Like if it were me the person that can not deliver the project because I am having some kind of issue if someone gave me a chance like the one I suggested I would really appreciate it. So if I add that, would it make the question more "valid"?

Comment: @Mykazuki as long as you explain how you've been there yourself (or in a similar situation), and that you explain why you think this would work, the answer is valid, regardless of its quality (I'm not saying yours is bad, I'm talking generalities here). So two points to remember : 1- explain how you've been in a similar situation yourself and 2- why you think what you're offering would work.

Comment: I think I updated my answer to reflect your suggestions, thanks a lot for your feedback.