# Celebrating the answers of 2020

Tags: discussion, answers, site-promotion

A new year is approaching and even though 2020 wasn't the year anyone expected, we can still celebrate some part of it.

That's why, under this question, I am inviting all of you to post about one IPS answer that you really liked this year.

The rules:

- You can only link one answer
- The answer must have been written in 2020
- You can't post an answer of yours (but you can post an answer to one of the questions you asked)
- The question mustn't be closed
- The answer must respect [IPS backup rules](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3583/1599)

**Why should you do it?**

The idea is to give visibility to the best answers IPS gets. This way, more people can go read it and potentially upvote it. Also, depending on the answers we get, I *might* give a bounty to one of the submitted answers

---

For people having a hard time find an answer to post about, here is what I can suggest:

- Go to your profile and then click on "Votes", then "Upvote". You can now see all the posts you upvoted by anti chronological order.

Or

- Select a few tags that talk about topics you like (for example: "family" and "mental-health") and then go through the answers related to these tags. It will greatly reduce the number of answers you have to read through.

Answer (score 5):

We had a lot of great answers this year and it was hard to choose. But after debating it with myself, I am choosing to highlight [this answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/24279/21067) by "IMightBeAmelia".

It's an answer to the question: "How can I tell my date that one of her close friends outed her to me as trans?"

Answer (score 3):

I posted a question on the behalf of a relative and was struck by the quality of [AsheraH's answer](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/26452/22143) to the question "How to gain group respect in a workplace setting?".

The answer was quite throughout from giving new perspective to detailing strategies to answer the problem.