# Improving the help/how-to-answer page

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I recently wrote my first Answer only to then hear someone suggest it [needed personal experience included](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/posts/26887/revisions).

Before writing it, though, I had gone through the [help center](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and it didn't have anything about including sources or personal experience.

There's much more info available [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3583/what-are-the-citation-expectations-of-answers-on-ips-stack-exchange) and [here](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3266/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer/3269#3269), but in my view the help center is the go-to for new users.

So, should the help center page be updated, with either the information from those meta pages or maybe just links to them?

Comment: The help/how-to-answer page sadly isn't one that moderators can update themselves (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259914/369802), but perhaps there is a case to be made that IPS is different enough to ask for our own help/how-to-answer.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell Did you get any response on that?