# How do we deal with chatGPT generated answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, policy

As already discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/is-there-a-list-of-chatgpt-discussions-and-policies-for-our-sites), we'll probably  be dealing soon with some content generated by AI such as chatGPT.

**What should we do with these posts?**

Answer (score 6):

These posts will fail to meet the [citation expectations](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3583/1599) as ChatGPT is not a reliable objective source and also as an AI doesn't have any experience to share. As such posts copied from it should be flagged and deleted. A moderator flag (instead of the standard 'Not An Answer's ones for these kinds of posts) would be appreciated so we can warn the ones posting these to not do so again.

Comment: What if the post collects some data from experiences from others or science data? Would it still be considered off-topic?

Comment: @OldPadawan I'd say yes, it would still be 'not an answer'. ChatGPT comes up with fake sources, so any referencing it does shouldn't be trusted. And if users can be lazy enough to just copy-paste ChatGPT, it is fair enough for the rest of us to treat those posts with the same laziness and not to have to go and verify any sources used to find out if they're fake or not.

Comment: Fair enough I guess