# Should the behavior that posts get removed from the low quality queue if edited externally and marked "high-quality" by the system be disabled here?

Tags: discussion, answers, review-queues

When someone makes a new post on any network site, the system will take it through a "quality test" to determine its quality of writing (e.g., whether it's likely to be an attempt to answer the question, how well it uses grammar, punctuation, correct spelling, etc.), and if it fails, it will put the post into the *Low quality posts* review queue. Posts are also placed there if a user flags them as "very low quality", and in the case of answers, "not an answer".

Here on this site, many posts in the queue are in there because of the latter (user flags) and not because of the former (failing the system's quality check). This is primarily because this site [upholds additional guidelines](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3321/11936) for deleting answers than the rest of the network. As such, the purpose of the queue here on this site is a bit different from most of the network: it's not just to find and delete *low-quality* posts, but also any answer that doesn't meet the site's guidelines, even if they aren't "low-quality" as such per the above definition. The above guidelines link also states the following:

> In many cases, answers that fall into the above categories which make them eligible for deletion are longer and higher-quality than typical "low-quality" answers across the network. However, they should still be reviewed as "Recommend Deletion" or "Delete".

Today, I remembered one of the system's behaviors: if a post that is being reviewed in the *Low quality posts* queue gets an edit *outside of the review queue* and the edited post passes the system's quality check, the system [will invalidate the review task](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190581/377214). Again, the quality check only checks for things like proper grammar and spelling, and not whether an answer is likely to fit within this site's guidelines. This behavior means that **answers that don't meet the site's guidelines will end up getting removed from review if they get edited** (if they're not also low-quality).

Should this behavior of invalidating low quality reviews if a post is edited and it passes the system's quality test be disabled for this site?